# Vagrant ssh connect to host 127.0.0.1:2222 port 22: Bad file number

Tags: ssh, vagrant, vagrant-windows

Whenever I try to connect to my local Vagrant, I get this error when I run `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222` from the Windows git bash:

```
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1:2222 port 22: Bad file number
```

It was working previously, so I'm not sure what could have caused this. When I try to do an SFTP connection in PHPStorm 8, I get this error:

```
Connection to '127.0.0.1' failed.
SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many authentication failures for vagrant
```

I've tried `vagrant destroy` with `vagrant box remove laravel/homestead` and then recreating the box from a backup I had that previously worked using `vagrant box add laravel/homestead homestead.box` but I still get the same errors.

I'm on Windows 7.

What can I do to get access to my vagrant box commandline again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your vagrant is up and running by command :  *vagrant up*

and then do *vagrant ssh*. It will connect to vagrant localhost

Comment: I was able to connect with `vagrant ssh`, so thank you! Any idea why a standard ssh connection attempt would start failing?

Comment: try standard ssh connection with ssh vagrant@localhost  and before that don't forget to check entry of localhost in host file.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by [outboundexplorer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2387780/outboundexplorer) above is the correct one I believe.
Here is my step-by-step approach on how I did this:

**Step 1: Find out exactly what SSH settings to use**

Ensure the vagrant box is running (you've done `vagrant up` that is)

From the command line, go to your project directory (the one where the Vagrantfile is located) and run `vagrant ssh-config`.

You'll get an output like this:

```
Host default
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    User ubuntu
    Port 2222
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    PasswordAuthentication no
    IdentityFile C:/Projects/my-test-project/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    LogLevel FATAL
```

**Step 2: Setting up PHPStorm to SFTP to the Vagrant box**

Based on the config settings shown above, I set up the following SFTP remote deployment server:

- SFTP host: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 2222
- Root path: `/home/ubuntu/my-test-project` (this is the folder inside the Vagrant box where the files will be uploaded to, change to whatever suits your needs)
- User name: ubuntu
- Auth type: Select "Key pair (OpenSSH or PuTTY)"
- Private key file: Point to the `IdentityFile` path shown (C:/Projects/....)

... and that was it.

Comment: `vagrant ssh-config` was the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try command:

ssh **-p 2222** vagrant@127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I got this same failure when using PHpStorm to SSH into the VirtualBox guest machine that i had set up with Vagrant.  Everything worked fine before I upgraded to Windows 10.  After upgrading, first of all i had to upgrade to VirtualBox and Vagrant latest versions to get everything to work on Windows 10.

But then i couldn't ssh into the guest machine using the PhpStorm ssh client.  After much reading, everything seemed to suggest that I had too many ssh-keys installed on my Windows machine, but checking `regedit` just showed that I only had a couple of keys which should be less than the suggested max 5 keys (as default).  In the end i did `vagrant ssh` which didn't allow me to ssh into the guest machine, but it did reconfirm the ssh details for me.  I then realized that after all the new installs it didn't want me to use the `C:\Users\Andy\.vagrant.d\insecure_private_key` key but instead use a key that it had placed within the project itself at `C:/Users/Andy/CodeLab5/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key`.

Everything is working as it should again now :)