# Can't connect in Ubuntu box from Windows host in Vagrant

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, vagrant

I'm having problems trying to ssh in an ubuntu box inside my windows machine. I'm following the basic Getting Started tutorial from Vagrant site (http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/up.html)

Software Versions:

Vagrant: 1.7.2

Virtualbox: 4.3.22

SO: Windows 7

Box: hashicorp/precise32

The scenario:

When I hit `vagrant up` everything goes according to plan: services and vm starts, but in the final step, which vagrant tests the ssh, it fails after severals `Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...`

After that when I open the Virtualbox GUI, I can log in the box and check that `openssh-server` is running. When I try to ssh through the command line I get the error:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 2222

ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222: Bad file number
```

When I hit `vagrant ssh` (with the logs in INFO level), I get this output:

```
INFO global: Vagrant version: 1.7.2
 INFO global: Ruby version: 2.0.0
 INFO global: RubyGems version: 2.0.14
 INFO global: VAGRANT_EXECUTABLE="C:\\dev\\tools\\Vagrant\\embedded\\gems\\gems\\vagrant-1.7.2\\bin\\vagrant"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_EMBEDDED_DIR="C:\\dev\\tools\\Vagrant\\embedded"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_ENV="1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_VERSION="2"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INTERNAL_BUNDLERIZED="1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_LOG="INFO"
 INFO global: Plugins:
 INFO global:   - bundler = 1.7.11
 INFO global:   - mime-types = 1.25.1
 INFO global:   - rdoc = 4.0.0
 INFO global:   - rest-client = 1.6.8
 INFO global:   - vagrant-share = 1.1.3
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: box command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: destroy command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: global-status command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: halt command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: help command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: init command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: list-commands command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: vagrant-login
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: package command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: plugin command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: provision command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: push command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: rdp command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: reload command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: resume command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh-config command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: status command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: suspend command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: up command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: version command
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh communicator
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: winrm communicator
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Arch guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: CoreOS guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Darwin guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Debian guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ESXi guest.
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Fedora guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: FreeBSD guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Funtoo guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Gentoo guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Linux guest.
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Mint guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: NetBSD guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: NixOS guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OmniOS guest.
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OpenBSD guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: PLD Linux guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: RedHat guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SmartOS guest.
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Solaris guest.
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Solaris 11 guest.
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SUSE guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: TinyCore Linux guest.
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Ubuntu guest
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Windows guest.
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Arch host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: BSD host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Mac OS X host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: FreeBSD host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Gentoo host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Linux host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: null host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Red Hat host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Slackware host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SUSE host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Windows host
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: kernel
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: kernel
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: docker-provider
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Hyper-V provider
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: VirtualBox provider
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ansible
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: CFEngine Provisioner
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: chef
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: docker
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: file
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: puppet
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: salt
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: shell
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: atlas
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ftp
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: heroku
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: local-exec
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: noop
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: NFS synced folders
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: RSync synced folders
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SMB synced folders
 INFO global: Loading plugins!
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: vagrant-share
 INFO vagrant: `vagrant` invoked: ["ssh"]
 INFO environment: Environment initialized (#<Vagrant::Environment:0x36893d0>)
 INFO environment:   - cwd: C:/dev/local-server
 INFO environment: Home path: C:/Users/vitallan/.vagrant.d
 INFO environment: Local data path: C:/dev/local-server/.vagrant
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_plugins_loaded
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x2c494c8>
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_load
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x2cc93a0>
 INFO cli: CLI: [] "ssh" []
 INFO loader: Set :root = #<Pathname:C:/dev/local-server/Vagrantfile>
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:home, :root]
 INFO command: Active machine found with name default. Using provider: virtualbox
 INFO environment: Getting machine: default (virtualbox)
 INFO environment: Uncached load of machine.
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "--version"]
 INFO meta: Using VirtualBox driver: VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Driver::Version_4_3
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 INFO loader: Set "27710496_machine_default" = []
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:home, :root, "27710496_machine_default"]
 INFO box_collection: Box found: hashicorp/precise32 (virtualbox)
 INFO environment: Running hook: authenticate_box_url
 INFO host: Autodetecting host type for [#<Vagrant::Environment: C:/dev/local-server>]
 INFO host: Detected: windows!
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 2 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x376dbc8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::LoginCommand::AddAuthentication:0x4727a18>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::LoginCommand::AddAuthentication:0x4727a18>
 INFO loader: Set :"28616568_hashicorp/precise32_virtualbox" = #<Pathname:C:/Users/vitallan/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise32/1.0.0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile>
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:"28616568_hashicorp/precise32_virtualbox", :home, :root, "27710496_machine_default"]
 INFO machine: Initializing machine: default
 INFO machine:   - Provider: VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Provider
 INFO machine:   - Box: #<Vagrant::Box:0x474dfb0>
 INFO machine:   - Data dir: C:/dev/local-server/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "--version"]
 INFO meta: Using VirtualBox driver: VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Driver::Version_4_3
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "d2575078-1bc6-448b-9c70-04e21249f33b"]
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "d2575078-1bc6-448b-9c70-04e21249f33b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO command: With machine: default (#<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Provider:0x487e4f8 @logger=#<Log4r::Logger:0x487e4c8 @fullname="vagrant::provider::virtualbox", @outputters=[], @additive=true, @name="virtualbox", @path="vagrant::provider", @parent=#<Log4r::Logger:0x37e65e8 @fullname="vagrant", @outputters=[#<Log4r::StderrOutputter:0x375fd50 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x375fc18>, @name="stderr", @level=0, @formatter=#<Log4r::DefaultFormatter:0x375dbd8 @depth=7>, @out=#<IO:<STDERR>>>], @additive=true, @name="vagrant", @path="", @parent=#<Log4r::RootLogger:0x37e6540 @level=0, @outputters=[]>, @level=2, @trace=false>, @level=2, @trace=false>, @machine=#<Vagrant::Machine: default (VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Provider)>, @driver=#<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Driver::Meta:0x4897560 @logger=#<Log4r::Logger:0x48a4148 @fullname="vagrant::provider::virtualbox::meta", @outputters=[], @additive=true, @name="meta", @path="vagrant::provider::virtualbox", @parent=#<Log4r::Logger:0x487e4c8 @fullname="vagrant::provider::virtualbox", @outputters=[], @additive=true, @name="virtualbox", @path="vagrant::provider", @parent=#<Log4r::Logger:0x37e65e8 @fullname="vagrant", @outputters=[#<Log4r::StderrOutputter:0x375fd50 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x375fc18>, @name="stderr", @level=0, @formatter=#<Log4r::DefaultFormatter:0x375dbd8 @depth=7>, @out=#<IO:<STDERR>>>], @additive=true, @name="vagrant", @path="", @parent=#<Log4r::RootLogger:0x37e6540 @level=0, @outputters=[]>, @level=2, @trace=false>, @level=2, @trace=false>, @level=2, @trace=false>, @interrupted=false, @vboxmanage_path="C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", @uuid="d2575078-1bc6-448b-9c70-04e21249f33b", @version="4.3.22", @driver=#<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Driver::Version_4_3:0x48d4568 @logger=#<Log4r::Logger:0x48ed108 @fullname="vagrant::provider::virtualbox_4_3", @outputters=[], @additive=true, @name="virtualbox_4_3", @path="vagrant::provider", @parent=#<Log4r::Logger:0x37e65e8 @fullname="vagrant", @outputters=[#<Log4r::StderrOutputter:0x375fd50 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x375fc18>, @name="stderr", @level=0, @formatter=#<Log4r::DefaultFormatter:0x375dbd8 @depth=7>, @out=#<IO:<STDERR>>>], @additive=true, @name="vagrant", @path="", @parent=#<Log4r::RootLogger:0x37e6540 @level=0, @outputters=[]>, @level=2, @trace=false>, @level=2, @trace=false>, @interrupted=false, @vboxmanage_path="C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", @uuid="d2575078-1bc6-448b-9c70-04e21249f33b">>, @cap_logger=#<Log4r::Logger:0x491d600 @fullname="vagrant::capability_host::vagrantplugins::providervirtualbox::provider", @outputters=[], @additive=true, @name="provider", @path="vagrant::capability_host::vagrantplugins::providervirtualbox", @parent=#<Log4r::Logger:0x37e65e8 @fullname="vagrant", @outputters=[#<Log4r::StderrOutputter:0x375fd50 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x375fc18>, @name="stderr", @level=0, @formatter=#<Log4r::DefaultFormatter:0x375dbd8 @depth=7>, @out=#<IO:<STDERR>>>], @additive=true, @name="vagrant", @path="", @parent=#<Log4r::RootLogger:0x37e6540 @level=0, @outputters=[]>, @level=2, @trace=false>, @level=2, @trace=false>, @cap_host_chain=[[:virtualbox, #<#<Class:0x491d8d0>:0x4b76518>]], @cap_args=[#<Vagrant::Machine: default (VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Provider)>], @cap_caps={:docker=>#<Vagrant::Registry:0x491d7f8 @items={:public_address=>#<Proc:0x3806538@C:/dev/tools/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/docker/plugin.rb:54>, :proxy_machine=>#<Proc:0x3806490@C:/dev/tools/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/docker/plugin.rb:59>}, @results_cache={}>, :hyperv=>#<Vagrant::Registry:0x491d780 @items={:public_address=>#<Proc:0x380ed10@C:/dev/tools/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/hyperv/plugin.rb:25>}, @results_cache={}>, :virtualbox=>#<Vagrant::Registry:0x491d708 @items={:forwarded_ports=>#<Proc:0x383fcd0@C:/dev/tools/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/plugin.rb:27>, :nic_mac_addresses=>#<Proc:0x383fc58@C:/dev/tools/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/plugin.rb:32>, :public_address=>#<Proc:0x2a38508@C:/dev/tools/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-share-1.1.3/lib/vagrant-share.rb:39>}, @results_cache={}>}>)
 INFO machine: Calling action: ssh on provider VirtualBox (d2575078-1bc6-448b-9c70-04e21249f33b)
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x460fde8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::CheckVirtualbox:0x4686480>
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "--version"]
 INFO meta: Using VirtualBox driver: VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Driver::Version_4_3
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "list", "hostonlyifs"]
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::CheckCreated:0x4686468>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "d2575078-1bc6-448b-9c70-04e21249f33b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::CheckAccessible:0x4686450>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "d2575078-1bc6-448b-9c70-04e21249f33b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::CheckRunning:0x4686438>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "d2575078-1bc6-448b-9c70-04e21249f33b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SSHExec:0x4686420>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "d2575078-1bc6-448b-9c70-04e21249f33b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "d2575078-1bc6-448b-9c70-04e21249f33b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin/ssh.EXE"]
 INFO ssh: Invoking SSH: ["vagrant@127.0.0.1", "-p", "2222", "-o", "Compression=yes", "-o", "DSAAuthentication=yes", "-o", "LogLevel=FATAL", "-o", "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-o", "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null", "-o", "IdentitiesOnly=yes", "-i", "C:/Users/vitallan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]
```

Does anyone know how can I ssh in my box?

EDIT: i tried openning new forwardding doors (like @user1389596 suggested), but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, ssh 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address (the same machine).  Shouldn't you use the local LAN IP of your ubuntu server intead?

Comment: with the port forwarding of vagrant i'm not quite sure. Hitting `vagrant ssh-config` returns
`Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222 `

Comment: Ah, connecting to vagrant.  Should it use the command `vagrant ssh` ?  For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757642/vagrant-ssh-connect-to-host-127-0-0-12222-port-22-bad-file-number

Comment: Tried that too. As I said in the question, when i hit `vagrant ssh` it does nothing. Putting logs in INFO level outputs all those lines that I put in the question.

Comment: It looks like vagrant is running on windows, which might be the issue (it won't know the ip of the virtual machine).  Something like this might work better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-virtualbox-guest-externally-through-a-host

Comment: Not sure if I undestood right, but the solution of this question was in port forwarding.  If that is the case, vagrant already does that, forwardding host port 2222 to guest port 22. 
`NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = ssh, protocol = tcp, host ip = 127.0.0.1, host port = 2222, guest ip = , guest port = 22`

Comment: is guest ip =  blank?  I'm not sure how vagrant knows where to route the traffic, if it's running on windows.  On the other hand, if virtual box does the port forwarding, it knows the target IP.  So, I'm not sure that vagrant helps in this case...I think it would still need forward to a port forward (other than 22) defined in virtual box

Comment: IOW, you can set up a port forward in virtual box with VBoxManage modifyvm myserver --natpf1 "ssh,tcp,,3022,,22"   Then ssh localhost:3022 on windows would forward to ubuntu's port 22

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72146/discussion-between-allan-vital-and-user1389596).